# how to add a plugin to tinymce 3.x editor after init (dynamically)?

Tags: javascript, tinymce-3

Is there a way to add a plugin to a tinymce editor on demand? Meaning, after the page loads, tinymce editor has been initialized etc? Say, on click of a button?

Answer (score 1):

The `AddOnManager` seems to be your friend ([documentation](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/js/tinymce/docs/api/index.html#class_tinymce.AddOnManager.html))

So it would look something like

```
tinymce.AddOnManager.load('myAddOn', '/scripts/addOns/myAddOn.js', 
    function(plugin) {
        tinymce.AddOnManager.add('myAddOn', plugin);
    });
```